# Prevent null updates in detached entity framework objects

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, n-tier-architecture

Using EF6 Framework4.5 – Creating my first n-tier app and first EF experience. I have CRUD working but one issue that I have a work-a-around but don’t like it. There must be a better way.

When data object is returned from my UI layer to the DAL layer, it has been detached, so I flag EntityState as “Modified.” But then it updates all columns in the db. Values that were not loaded in the form view (and not submitted) obviously are null and updated to such in the db.

**1) My first solution does work:**
Store the object in session in the UI layer and loop through the object updating edited values when the form is submitted. Thus, original values are passed back unchanged and updated to original values. I don’t think this would be best practice though.

**2) The solution I think I want:**
I am looking for a helper function in the DAL layer to loop through all values in the returned object and flag only non-null values as “IsModified” before calling SaveChanges.

I have found examples in C# on how to check for changed value but not null. (I am still a vb guy anyway. Don't hate.)

---

A)  Is solution #2 a good way to do this?

B)  Has anyone a piece of good to help me?

Thank you.

BTW, this is my best stab at it so far: (Errors on “CurrentValues”)

```
Public Overridable Function MarkEntriesModified(entity As Object)

    Dim dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity)

    'Ensure only non-null values are inserted
    For Each [property] In dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames
        If Not IsDBNull(dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue(Of Object)([property])) Then
            dbEntityEntry.[Property]([property]).IsModified = True
        End If
    Next
    Return entity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this architecture. So if you are using EF then I suppose you have edmx updated and correctly representing your database objects.

eg: Say you wan to update Customer data in customer table

- Create a Customer class.
- when you extract a particular customer, get an instance of the
  customer created.
- pass this instance to the UI
- and pass the instance back to Business layer to save

this way you don't loose anything in between.

[some sample code](http://pastethis.in/?paste=1503)